# reactjs: clear cookie http only on logout

Tags: reactjs

i have this for logout on client-side:

```
  public logout = async (): Promise<void> => {
    return this.rootStore.AxiosStore.get('/users/me/logout')
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.response.data.message))
      .finally(() => {
        this.isAuth = false;
        this.inProgress = false;
        this.rootStore.currentUserStore.currentUser = null;
        this.rootStore.cookieStore.removeToken('emsi');
        this.rootStore.cookieStore.removeToken('@Emasa/Refresh-Token');
      });
  };
```

and this on my backend:

```
  private logout = async (
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    next: NextFunction,
  ) => {
    try {
      const id = request.cookies['emsi'];
      const refreshToken = request.cookies['@Emasa/Refresh-Token'];
      const ip = ensure(getRequestIpAddress(request));
      const result = await container
        .resolve(LogoutUseCase)
        .execute({ refreshToken, id, ip });
      if (result.isLeft()) return next(result.value);
      response.cookie('emsi', {},{maxAge: 0});
      response.cookie('@Emasa/Refresh-Token', {},{maxAge: 0});
      return response.json(result.value);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
```

I tried to set my two cookies with {maxAge: 0}, to clear my browser's http only cookies, but they are still there, how can I clear this from the backend?

Comment: you have to set it to no value from your backend

Comment: like this ?      response.cookie('emsi',{maxAge: 0});
      response.cookie('@Emasa/Refresh-Token', {maxAge: 0});